# Closed form expression for the sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I am trying to evaluate the following limit,

$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum\limits_{k=2}^n\frac{1-e^{-(x_k-x_{k-1})}}{1+e^{-(x_k-x_{k-1})}} $$

The points $\{x_1,..,x_n\} \in [0,1]$ are ordered $x_1 < x_2 < ... < x_n$ and form a partition of $[0,1]$. Moreover, the maximum difference $x_j - x_{j-1}$ tends to zero. After simulating this, I conjecture that the limit is $\frac{1}{2}$, but I would like to know if there is a way of verifying this analytically.

Comment: I suppose the $x_i$'s form a partition of $[0,1]$. If that is the case and the limit is perhaps sought when the norm of partition tends to $0$. You should convert your sum into a Riemann sum (approximately) and see the limit as $1/2$.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by nested. The result holds when norm ie max difference $x_j-x_{j-1}$ tends to $0$. This is most easily verified for uniform case $x_j=j/n$.

Comment: Ok here is a hint. Can you write the kth term of sum as $(x_k-x_{k-1})/2 + o((x_k-x_{k-1})) $?

Comment: I'm assuming you did a Taylor expansion on the numerator and denominator?

Comment: Yes and I think you can now very well post a good answer. Do give it a try.

Comment: Does this mean that for an arbitrary infinite sequence $0\le x_1\lt x_2\lt x:3\lt ...\le1$ this limit is $1/2?$ I can't believe that this is true.

Comment: @miracle173: why do you doubt this? What is your idea behind this sum?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh When you have two sequences $a,x_2,x_3,..$ and $b,x_2,x_3,..$ then the difference of the infinite sums (if they exists) is the difference of the first term of these sums, which is not $0$ if $a\ne b$ so both limits cannot be $1/2$ at the same time

Comment: @miracle173: do you see this as some sort of Riemann sum (not exactly but approximately) so that each term of the sum tends to $0$. Note that each $x_i$ depends on $n$. Try to see the definition of a [Riemann sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum).

Comment: @miracle173 Shouldn't the difference between $a$ and $b$ tend to zero as there are more and more points?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh No, I don't see that as Rieman sum because this cannot be concluded from the OP. The x_i do not depend on n if one interpretes the problem in the way it is stated in the question. So if the problem text does not reflect the problem the OP should change the text of hi post.

Comment: @Flowsnake No, not if one reads the problem in the way you wrote it down.

Comment: @miracle173: I had asked for clarification from asker (see my comments), and asker was indicating something along those lines. Anyway it's upto the asker to clarify. I gave my point of view which the asker may well reject or accept. In case of acceptance the question should be updated accordingly.

Comment: @Flowsnake: Perhaps you can update your question to add that points $x_i$ form a partition of $[0,1]$ instead of using things like $[0,1]^n$. This will make your question unambiguous.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yes, it is up to the asker to update the question. The intention of my first comment  ("Does this mean...") was to ask Flowsnake but maybe it was sent to you, because my comment follows your comment immediately.

Comment: Is your stealth edit an attempt to fix the problem that I raised ?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions and assistance. No the edit was in response to the issues raised by the two other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum\limits_{k=2}^n\frac{1-e^{-(x_k-x_{k-1})}}{1+e^{-(x_k-x_{k-1})}}\approx\sum\limits_{k=2}^n\frac{x_k-x_{k-1}}2=\frac{x_n-x_1}2$$

is not a good sign that the limit has a defined value.

---

More specifically, let $x_k-x_{k-1}=\frac\Delta{n-1}$ for all $k$.

$$\sum\limits_{k=2}^n\frac{1-e^{-(x_k-x_{k-1})}}{1+e^{-(x_k-x_{k-1})}}=(n-1)\tanh\frac\Delta{2(n-1)}\to\frac\Delta2$$ which is not necessarily $\frac12$.

---

But if you enforce $x_1=0,x_n=1$, the claim will hold if the convergence of $x_k-x_{k-1}$ is uniform. This is thanks to smoothness of the hyperbolic tangent.

Comment: Can I simply enforce that $x_1 \rightarrow 0$ and $x_n \rightarrow 1$ uniformly? Or is it necessary to set them equal to 0 and 1 resp.?

Comment: @Flowsnake: this is implicit in my first answer.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
\frac{1-e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}}=\tanh\left(\frac x2\right)\tag1
$$
Using the fact that for $x\ge0$, $\tanh(x)\ge0$, and that
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\tanh\left(\frac x2\right)=\frac12\left(1-\tanh^2\left(\frac x2\right)\right)\tag2
$$
we can easily see that for $x\ge0$,
$$
\frac x2-\frac{x^3}{24}\le\tanh\left(\frac x2\right)\le\frac x2\tag3
$$
Suppose that $x_k-x_{k-1}\le\Delta$ for all $2\le k\le n$, then
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1-e^{-(x_k-x_{k-1})}}{1+e^{-(x_k-x_{k-1})}}
&\le\frac12\sum_{k=2}^n(x_k-x_{k-1})\\
&=\frac12(x_n-x_1)\tag4
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1-e^{-(x_k-x_{k-1})}}{1+e^{-(x_k-x_{k-1})}}
&\ge\frac12\sum_{k=2}^n(x_k-x_{k-1})-\frac1{24}\sum_{k=2}^n(x_k-x_{k-1})^3\\
&\ge\frac12(x_n-x_1)\left(1-\frac{\Delta^2}{12}\right)\tag5
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, if $0\le x_k\le1$ and $0\le x_k-x_{k-1}\le\Delta$, we have
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac12(x_n-x_1)\left(1-\frac{\Delta^2}{12}\right)\le\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1-e^{-(x_k-x_{k-1})}}{1+e^{-(x_k-x_{k-1})}}\le\frac12(x_n-x_1)}\tag6
$$